# can a feed token be created in client side or only server side?

Tags: token, feed, getstream-io

can a feed token be created in client side or only server side? I am building an Ionic app with a nodejs backend. Just wanted to know if I need to create feed tokens for my users on server side first or if its possible to do that in client side.

Comment: It don't really understand what is your feed token ? Is that an access token to call an API ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only create feed tokens on the server side. You can generate either read only or read/write tokens. (read only is recommended for most use cases)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a feed token on either as long as you have the secret and api key plus the js getstream library.

However, you don't want your secret to be stored on the client side app. Best practise is to have the secret stored on the service side and generate a read-only token for the client.